# EventFilter capturing events from Different Objects on Mac and Windows

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I am working on an application for Windows and Mac. I am noticing different behavior for Mac and Windows.

When I set a QLIstView for a QComboBox and try to capture the Enter/Return press events from the PopUp of the comboBox, the eventFilter gets the event from the QListView on Windows and QComboBox on Mac,
Thus, the same code results in different output because of this.

Here's the code:

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QEvent>
#include<QComboBox>
#include<QListView>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter( QObject * inObject, QEvent * inEvent );

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QComboBox * mComboBox;
    QListView * mListView;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include<QStandardItemModel>
#include<QStandardItem>
#include<QList>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QKeyEvent>
#include<QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui( new Ui::MainWindow ),
    mComboBox( new QComboBox() ),
    mListView( new QListView( mComboBox ) )
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mComboBox->setFixedSize( 200, 25 );
    mListView->setFixedWidth( 200 );
    QWidget * centralWidget = new QWidget( this );
    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout( centralWidget );

    QStandardItem * font1 = new QStandardItem( "Item1" );
    QStandardItem * font2 = new QStandardItem( "Item2" );
    QStandardItem * font3 = new QStandardItem( "Item3" );
    QStandardItem * font4 = new QStandardItem( "Item4" );
    QStandardItem * font5 = new QStandardItem( "Item5" );

    QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel( mListView);

    model->insertRow( 0, font1 );
    model->insertRow( 1, font2 );
    model->insertRow( 2, font3 );
    model->insertRow( 3, font4 );
    model->insertRow( 4, font5 );

    mListView->setStyleSheet( "background-color: yellow" );

    mComboBox->setModel( model );
    mComboBox->setView( mListView );

    layout->addWidget( mComboBox );

    centralWidget->setLayout( layout );
    setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
    mListView->installEventFilter( this );
    mComboBox->installEventFilter( this );
}


bool
MainWindow::eventFilter( QObject * inObject, QEvent * inEvent )
{
    if( inObject == mListView )
    {
        if( inEvent->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
        {
            QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast< QKeyEvent * >( inEvent );
            if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return )
            {
                qDebug() << " From mListView";
            }
        }
    }
    else if( inObject == mComboBox )
    {
        if( inEvent->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
        {
            QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast< QKeyEvent * >( inEvent );
            if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return )
            {
                qDebug() << " From mComboBox";
            }
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter( inObject, inEvent );
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

see the images below for output from Mac and Windows

[image: Windows output]

[image: Mac output]